# Error while detaching AKS cluster through Azure ML SDK extension

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service

I created an AKS cluster using Azure Machine Learning SDK extension and I attached to the workspace created. When the cluster is created and attached, I doesn't show any error. When I am trying to detach it from workspace, it is not accepting the operations.

I would like to detach the existing AKS cluster from workspace either by program manner, using CLI or even using Azure portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are using any **extensions of SDK or Azure CLI** for machine learning to detach AKS cluster, it **will not work** and it will not get deleted or detached. Instead, we need to use **Azure CLI with AKS**. There are two types of implementations we can perform.

**Python:**

```
Aks_target.detach()
```

**Azure CLI:**

Before performing this step, we need to get the details of the working AKS cluster name attached to our workspace. Resource Group details and workspace name

```
az ml computertarget detach -n youraksname -g yourresourcegroup -w yourworkspacename
```